How do I make default option show up in dropdown menu with vue/inertia?
I am using Inertia, Vue3 and Laravel and I can't seem to get a dropdown menu to autopopulate with the first option. It is just blank. This is my code:
    <template>
        <form @submit.prevent="update">
          <div>
            <div @change="update">
              <input v-model="form.description" type="text" />
              <input v-model="form.amount" type="text" />
              <select v-model="form.frequency">
                <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
                <option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
              </select>
              <input v-model="form.day_deposited" type="text" />
            </div>
     
          </div>
        </form>
      </template>
     
      <script setup>
      import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
      const props = defineProps({
        income: Object,
      })
      const form = useForm({
        description: props.income.description,
        amount: props.income.amount,
        day_deposited: props.income.day_deposited,
        frequency: props.income.frequency,
      })
      const update = () => form.put(`/income/${props.income.id}`)
      </script>

I've tried using selected and form.defaults().

I got it working with
      <select v-model="form.frequency">
        <option :value=form.frequency>Monthly</option>
        <option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
        <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
      </select>

Thank you for your help.
Edit start
Added to answer itself because I have not yet earned enough reputation to comment: this answer is obviously wrong. Whenever user selects "Monthly" option he is not necessarily setting the value of form.frequency to "monthly", he is leaving the value unchanging, be it 'quarterly' or 'yearly'.
The correct answer is to be sure that the value of form.frequency is, by default, 'monthly' and at no point after onMounted may be anything other than 'monthly'|'quarterly'|'yearly'
Edit finished
Thank you! I got it working a different way today where the data actually posts to the database:
<template>
  <Edit v-for="income in incomes" :key="income.id" :income="income"/>

  <form @submit.prevent="create">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Description</label>
        <input v-model="form.description" type="text" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Amount</label>
        <input v-model="form.amount" type="text" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Day Deposited</label>
        <input v-model="form.day_deposited" type="text" />
      </div>

      <select v-model="form.frequency">
        <option>Monthly</option>
        <option>Quarterly</option>
        <option>Yearly</option>
      </select>

      <div>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import Edit from './Edit.vue'
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
defineProps({
  incomes: Array,
})

const form = useForm({
description: null,
amount: null,
frequency: "Monthly",
day_deposited: null,
})
const create = () => {
  console.log(form.frequency)
form.post('/income');
form.description = "";
form.amount = "";
form.frequency = "Monthly";
form.day_deposited = "";
}
</script>


The answer is to be sure that the value of form.frequency is, by default, 'monthly' and at no point after onMounted may be anything other than 'monthly'|'quarterly'|'yearly'. I don't know how useForm works, but if you don't get the first option to be autopopulated, it means that the value form.frequency has by default is not "monthly". There is nothing else to it.
You have to be sure that the value of form.frequency is absolutely the same as the value of the first (or any other) option.
The answer with <option :value=form.frequency>Monthly</option> is obviously wrong. Whenever user selects "Monthly" option he is not necessarily setting the value of form.frequency to "monthly", he is leaving the value unchanged, be it 'quarterly' or 'yearly'.
